# Yii2 tableName return values

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

Could you tell me what is the difference between function `tableName()` in class which return value {{%table_name}} and 'table_name' in Yii2 ??

```
public static function tableName(){
return {{%admin}};
}



public static function tableName(){
return 'admin';
}
```

Comment: `{{%admin}}` return "LIKE %admin" or end with admin result show. and `admin` show equal to `admin`

Comment: @GAMITG this is false.

Answer (score 4):

`'{{%admin}}'` will be prefixed with the [table prefix](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html#$tablePrefix-detail) if one is set. `'admin'` will not.

I can't find a reference for this exactly but it can be inferred from the docs and source code for `\yii\db\ActiveRecord::tableName()`.

[Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#tableName()-detail):

> By default this method returns the class name as the table name by calling `yii\helpers\Inflector::camel2id()` with prefix `yii\db\Connection::$tablePrefix`. If `yii\db\Connection::$tablePrefix` is 'tbl_', 'Customer' becomes 'tbl_customer', and 'OrderItem' becomes 'tbl_order_item'. You may override this method if the table is not named after this convention.

[Source Code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/ActiveRecord.php#L282) is:

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return '{{%' . Inflector::camel2id(StringHelper::basename(get_called_class()), '_') . '}}';
}
```